# ASP.NET MVC, Reeling in Unroutable Page Nesting

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

The concept of routes is nothing new, and it works great for the concept of `{area}/{controller}/{action}/{parameter}`, but few sites are standalone UI interaction.

Websites often need parts of themselves that aren't really dedicated to taking data, but presenting it. For instance one of the sites I am working on has a large part of itself dedicated to user interaction (which the MVC system solves expertly. A `Membership` area, a place to manage information, a way to purchase items, etc.) - but it also needs a part that functions more like an old-fashioned website, where you're simply looking at pages like a folder structure.

one solution I have found is to try a custom view engine. This worked, but I quick found myself lost in a convoluted routing scheme. Another I guess I could go with is to just have an `IgnoreRoute` and put files in the ignored folder like normal html/aspx, but I'd really rather have the option of using Controllers so that there is a chance I can have data returned from a database, etc in the future.

So let me show you my current scenario...

- Areas

  - Membership
  - Rules
  - Controllers

    - HomeController
    - FileView(string folder, string file)
  - Views

    - Home
    - General

      - Customize

        - Content
        - yyy.cshtml
      - xxx.cshtml

        - @Html.Partial("Content/yyy.cshtml")
      - xxx.cshtml
      - xxx.cshtml

etc. The `Rules` area is basically setup to function like a normal `/folder/file/` structure. So here is my Controller for it..

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Information/Home/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // **************************************
    // URL: /Rules/{controller}/{folder}/{file}
    // **************************************
    public ViewResult FileView(string folder, string filename)
    {
        return View(String.Format("{0}/{1}", folder, filename));
    }
}
```

Now, if I have a category, I simply have a lightweight controller that inherits from that Area's `HomeController`, like this...

```
public class GeneralController : Rules.Controllers.HomeController
{
    // **************************************
    // URL: /Rules/General/Customize/{id}
    // **************************************

    public ViewResult Customize(string id)
    {
        return FileView("Customize", id);
    }
}
```

So then, for each folder in the 'sub' controller, I have a single Route that takes in the name of the file.

This works, but I feel it's excessively clunky. Can anyone suggest a better alternative? There are just too many pages, and too much nesting, to have a full `ActionResult` for each one. I also want to maintain clean urls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you can use a catch-all route for the Membership area, route it to a controller (MembershipController?) and have that controller just render the view that is catched by the route, like this:

```
public class MembershipController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(string pageTitle)
    {
        return View(pageTitle);
    }
}
```

And the route:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Membership",
            "Membership/{*pageTitle}",
            new  {controller = "Membership", action = "Index", pageTitle = "NotFound"});
```

Of course, in the controller you should check whether the view exists or not, but this one should get you moving. Although I don't see why you want to have MVC in front of this when you just want to display (static?) content.

Comment: Well, the Membership area works fine, it isn't being called into question, it's the `Rules` area I am wanting to improve on. I've tried your approach and it _does_ work too - but it also lead to a lot of convoluted hyperlinks. However, what is this `*` in your `{*pageTitle}`? What does that do?

Comment: The * denotes a catch-all route, which means that everything from that position in the URL will be copied into the variable pageTitle.

Comment: Hey, wow, this might actually work. So am I able to do anything with a specific route if I include a catch all? Like say I have a specific controller action I want to be executable?

Comment: I want to have MVC in front of this because this is just a small portion of the entire website. Most of the website needs more dynamic content - but I've never seen a website that had 100% dynamic content... there's plenty that just needs to exist in files.

Comment: In that case the approach above will work nicely, and you still have the opportunity to have action filters etc. applied.